# Excel array formula help required - multiple criteria, multiple results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I need help - currently, all of my research on this topic is making things worse.

I have a worksheet with an undetermined amount of data (new data is being added constantly)

From this worksheet I have to collate all valid results that match the criterion of; no data entry in column L, and the data of column A must fall within the current month (I also need the same again but for the month previous... I figure I can easily adjust a single formula...)

Ideally, the returned results should list in a column the data pulled from the source sheet from column B

The results are being inserted into a dashboard page of a different tab within the same workbook.
I really would appreciate a little help.

Comment: Help us to help you : show some data and show what you have tried...

Answer (score 0):

Say our data is like:

[image]

Pick a cell, say **M1**, and enter the array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(($L$1:$L$26="")*(MONTH($A$1:$A$26)=3),$B$1:$B$26,""))
```

where the ***3*** stands for March:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and example... It's not quite what I'm after and unfortunately is limited by the fact that my data has multiple years of details, so just [Month] will pull previous years as well...
 

The other problem I'd prefer is to have the list laid into new rows akin to how the INDEX SMALL coupling works.
 

This link has a great example of the 'multiple result' effect that I'm chasing: https://www.get-digital-help.com/2013/12/13/lookup-and-return-multiple-values-sorted-in-a-custom-order/